# Create string object path from array of index/keys

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-final-form, zod

I'm using [Zod](https://github.com/vriad/zod) to validate the input of my application forms and when a validation error happens I receive an array of [errors](https://github.com/vriad/zod/blob/master/ERROR_HANDLING.md#zodsuberror) with a `message` property and a `path` property.

I need to transform the received `path` property to a `string` object path so I can use it to create a `ValidationError` for [React Final Form](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form).

Given `path`:

```js
["user", "name"]
["company", 0, "name"]
```

Expected `string` object path:

```js
"user.name"
"company[0].name"
```

Surprisingly I didn't find any code on Stack Overflow, Google Search or NPM that implements this :)

Comment: Seems like a pretty simple loop would work. Skip the first value; if the current value is a string, add a `.` and append the current value. If the current value is a number, add a `[`, the current value, and `]`. Continue through the array.

Comment: It would be much easier if you converted those to `user['name']` and `company['0']['name']` - less (no) edge cases to handle.

Comment: Yeah, I'd worry about more edge cases here.  Any string can be a property key, even ones which are not valid JS identifiers.

Comment: @jcalz sorry for commenting to you directly, but I think you might be interested to see https://stackoverflow.com/q/64676046/251311

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick attempt:

```js
const string_path = (path) =>
  path.reduce(
    (acc, item) => acc + (Number.isInteger(item) ? '[' + item + ']' : '.' + item),
    ''
  ).substring(1);

console.log(string_path(["user", "name"]));
console.log(string_path(["company", 0, "name"]));
```

Edit: So, from looking at @vich's post I learned that reduce will happily use the first element of the array as the accumulator if you don't specify one, so here's a slightly shorter version:

```js
const string_path = (path) =>
  path.reduce(
    (acc, item) => acc + (Number.isInteger(item) ? '[' + item + ']' : '.' + item)
  );

console.log(string_path(["user", "name"]));
console.log(string_path(["company", 0, "name"]));
console.log(string_path(["user"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce` to achieve what you want.

```js
const paths = ["company", 0, "name"];

const result = paths.reduce((acc, item) => {
  return typeof item === "string" ?
    acc + "." + item :
    `${acc}[${item}]`

}, "");

console.log(result.slice(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite trivial. It was worth making your own attempt.

`["user", "name"].reduce((string, item) => (typeof item === "number") ? string + "[" + item + "]" : string + "." + item)`

> "user.name"

`["company", 0, "name"].reduce((string, item) => (typeof item === "number") ? string + "[" + item + "]" : string + "." + item)`

> "company[0].name"

Comment: Thanks for your answer! yeah it was quite trivial but I am not sure about all the edge cases so that's why I finally decided to ask to SO. Anyways I decided to go for the approach that @zerkms commented as it makes me more confident about the code.